Grant permission to SQL database
I have a desktop application that I want users to access via RDP on their PC. I installed the application as admin in a Windows Server 2022 and made it available to other RDP users. All users see the shortcut on the desktop when they logon using RDP.
The application uses SQL Server database, and connection is managed by app.config file in the application.
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True

I can run the application using my admin account.
However, when using a regular user account, they can run the application but it is not connecting to the database. It returns 'login to DB failed for ad\thisuser'.
I have enabled remote connection for the database, and I have enabled TCP/IP connection (though I'm sure that was not necessary).
How do I grant permission to users to connect to the database?
This solution did not work for me: enable allow remote connection
(Windows Server 2022, SQL Server 2019)

Have you added them as users in the database? As a sidenote; giving users access to database is generally a bad idea. Give them access to a service that enforces access rights and consistency in the database. I would consider it an anti-pattern

And remote connection is irrelevant, so is RDP. The connection to the database happens locally.

Virdarlo: thanks for the comments. I am actually managing access to the database through the applications config file; they have no SSMS installed or anything. But despite having given this Remote Desktop Users login rights to the database, is still doesn't work! It seems to be looking at the logged in domain user, and not the app.config file

Hey, I'm making some headway... I have allowed a user in the [DatabaseName] > Security > Users, not Databases > Security > Logins. But now it is not opening the tables. Let me revert when I have figured out the object permissions as well...

You believe you have managed access; you have not. Users will be able to change DB directly. Coupled with the lack of knowledge about permissions on your database, this is disaster in the making. Take a step back, and re-design your software.

Vidarlo: we have previously had arguments with our  clients about access to "their databases" that over  the time, we really don't care if they have access to the databases, we let them have it. However, if I got a better way, i would implement it. For now, I just want them to work

The better way is to make an abstraction layer that enforces what actions a client can perform.

I see. I will explore more of this. May be I'm in a bit of a hurry at the moment. But I am always looking for better ways. Thank you so much. And if you point me to a better direction, i will gladly explore.

Though I think there is a better answers, but this is how I have done it:
Using admin login, Go to SSMS > Object Explorer > Server > Databases > [myDB]
Expand Security > Users > New User...
Under Select a Page

General:

In the main window,

User Type: Windows User
Username: Type or Select the user, eg, AD\User1.

Back to Select a page

Securables

In the main window

Search... > Add Objects > All Objects of Types.

Click Ok


Dialog of Select Object Types, Select Databases
Under Permissions for [DatabaseName], be sure to select at least:

Select

Insert

Delete

Connect

Execute

Update


Click Ok to finish
I'll be glad for this to be improved, especially if it can be done for an entire group. When I tried grouped users, I got the error that the login name is invalid

Or just grant the users the db_datareader and db_datawriter database roles.
